# Dialogflow with angular 6 should i use api-ai-javascript or base url?

Tags: angular6, dialogflow-es

Hi For integrating Angular 6 with dialogflow i saw two different ways.
1.
One is using Api-ai-javascript package which have some issues with dialogflow v2 version

```
import { ApiAiClient } from 'api-ai-javascript';
client = new ApiAiClient({ accessToken: this.token });
this.client.textRequest(msg)
               .then(res => {
                  const speech = res.result.fulfillment.speech;
                  const botMessage = new Message(speech, 'bot');
                  this.update(botMessage);
               });
```

2.
Also we can directly call the api "https://api.dialogflow.com/v2/query?v=20150910";

```
private baseURL: string = "https://api.dialogflow.com/v2/query?v=20150910";
public getResponse(query: string){
    let data = {
      query : query,
      lang: 'en',
      sessionId: '12345'
    }
    return this.http
      .post(`${this.baseURL}`, data, {headers: this.getHeaders()})
      .map(res => {
        return res.json()
      })
  }
```

Sample Link [here](https://hackernoon.com/chatbot-with-angular-5-dialogflow-fdac97fef681)

which is the suggested way for dialogflow integration
Api. ai is package seems like not used widely
please give me some suggestion and Best practices?

Answer (score 0):

I found a few YouTube tutorials that might help:

[Angular - Building Chatbot Using DialogFlow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4xDZtdYVxYE)

[Angular Chatbot with Dialogflow (API.ai)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKhV7-NF2OI)